# Legend of a raster map with categorical data

Tags: raster, cartography, r, legend

I would like to plot a raster containing 4 different values (1) with a categorical text legend describing the categories such as 2 but with colour boxes.

I've tried using legend such as :

```
legend( 1,-20,legend = c("land","ocean/lake", "rivers","water bodies"))
```

but I don't know how to associate one value to the displayed color. Is there a way to retrieve the colour displayed with 'plot' and to use it in the legend?

Initial raster[image]

Raster with legend
[image]

Comment: In addition to the absolutely right solution provided by @cengel, have a look at [this short tutorial](http://biologyforfun.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/taking-control-of-the-legend-in-raster-in-r/) on how to place the legend outside a plot. I think that would make sense in your particular case...

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136330/legend-of-a-raster-map-with-categorical-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not providing a reproducible code, so I made up a simple example that hopefully will allow you to tailor it to your needs.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(volcano)
plot(r, legend = FALSE, col = rev(terrain.colors(4)))
legend("topright", legend = c("category 1", "category 2", "category 3", "category 4"), fill = rev(terrain.colors(4)))
```

[image]