# Categorical Legend raster plot - R

Tags: raster, r, legend, plot

I have the following `RasterLayer` containing categorical values for each pixel. I am using the following code to plot it

```
par(xpd)=FALSE
plot(LC, legend=FALSE, col=c("lightcyan3","royalblue","forestgreen","coral3","papayawhip"),xaxt='n', yaxt='n') 

par(xpd=TRUE)
legend("bottom", legend=c("Urban","Water","Forest","Agriculture", "Bare soil"),fill=c("lightcyan3","royalblue","forestgreen","coral3","papayawhip"),horiz = TRUE, inset=-0.175)
```

[image]

In total I have 5 classes but due to the configuration of the legend only 4 are swhon. I want all the elements of the legend to be closer. I have tried to used `text.width=c(1,1,1,1)` for example to set the distances but it is not doing the job.

I am using a similar approach as the one proposed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73143/legend-of-a-raster-map-with-categorical-data) and was considering also to use the `rasterVis` package

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me - I get all five categories. Is this in RStudio or is it R's standard graphics output window? Have you tried this in a fresh R session as the first graphic you make (because sometimes previous plots can mess up graphics parameters).

Comment: I am using RStudio. I was considering previous plots were the cause. Due to my chain, this one is always produced after other plots. What I have done to try to solve it is: at the beginning of the script `graphics.off` and `opar<-par()`. Then, just before ploting this one I call `par(opar)` and then the code shown on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS @spacedman point it out, I think the problem is caused by previous plots that I have to create. Since I cannot have a fresh R session at this point, I am using a solution based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136330/legend-of-a-raster-map-with-categorical-data) and @ChristopherStephan [link](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/#factor). I solved my issue using the `rasterVis` package, which I find more convinient than using regular `plot` for raster.

Instead of using the code shown on the question, this one does the job.

First, I use `as.factor` to arrange my original `raster layer`

`myraster<-as.factor(myraster)`

Then I add an extra `attribute` that will be used for the legend

```
tar<-levels(myraster)[[1]]
tar[["landcover"]]<-c("Class1", "Class2")
levels(myraster)<-tar
```

Then I plot using `levelplot` from the `rasterVis` package

```
levelplot(myraster, col.regions=c("red","white"))
```

The legend shows now my classes and its size is appropriate

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to pass `cex = 0.75` in the legend function call?

However, I have no problems with the spacing for the legend with or without `cex`.

```
library(raster)

set.seed(100)
ras <- raster(ncol = 100, nrow = 100)
ras <- setValues(ras, (1:ncell(ras)) / 100 + rnorm(ncell(ras)) - 50)
plot(ras)

par(xpd = FALSE)
plot(
  ras,
  legend = FALSE,
  col = c(
    "lightcyan3",
    "royalblue",
    "forestgreen",
    "coral3",
    "papayawhip"
  ),
  xaxt = 'n',
  yaxt = 'n'
)

par(xpd = TRUE)
legend(
  "bottom",
  legend = c("Urban", "Water", "Forest", "Agriculture", "Bare soil"),
  fill = c(
    "lightcyan3",
    "royalblue",
    "forestgreen",
    "coral3",
    "papayawhip"
  ),
  horiz = TRUE,
  inset = -0.175
)
```

If you want to use the `rasterVis` package there is an example for categorical rasters [here](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/#factor).